# jcarousel popup on hover

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I am trying to create a popup on hover of each item on jcarousel.

You can see here:
http://help.infusionsoft.com/sites/all/themes/help_infusion12/templates/ce_player/jc.php

I have created a div and will display:none and then on hover I will remove the css display none. The only issue with this is that the popup divs are cutoff.

I have tried z-index with no luck. I have also attempted to change from overflow hidden however this will then display every item on the jcarousel which is not what I want.

Am I thinking about this popup idea the wrong way and need to do something else?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up re-working divs and used css to center popups on top of the jcarousel divs

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use http://fancybox.net/ to manage your popup

Comment: Do you know if there is an easy way you can specify location of the box or will it always appear in the center?

Comment: I dont think you can specify and x and y. But you can custom the padding, margin, height and width to make what you are looking for.

Comment: What do you think if I used absolute positioning instead and used jquery to detect the location of the hover to place the popup? This should get rid of the clipping issue no?